# Is there a workaround to the macOS 10.13 SDK breaking CGLCreatePBuffer?

Tags: macos, opengl, xcode9

I have a simple piece of code that successfully creates pbuffers when compiled against the macOS 10.12 SDK, but an update to the 10.13 SDK breaks things. I know that this tech is *very* deprecated.

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#import <OpenGL/gl3.h>
#import <OpenGL/glext.h>

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
    GLsizei width = 1024;
    GLsizei height = 1024;
    GLenum target = GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT;
    GLenum internalFormat = GL_RGBA;
    GLint maxLevel = 0;

    CGLPBufferObj pBuffer = NULL;
    CGLError error = kCGLNoError;

    error = CGLCreatePBuffer( width, height, target, internalFormat, maxLevel, &pBuffer );

    if( error )
    {
        NSLog(@"CGL Error %@ : %s", @(error), CGLErrorString( error ) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Using the 10.12 SDK, I get `kCGLNoError`, but using 10.13 it delivers `kCGLBadDrawable`.

Beyond transitioning to using e.g. framebuffer objects, what can I do to keep this piece of code going for a little bit longer?

Note: it's not even necessary to fully recompile the generated binary against a different macOS SDK. Changing the Mach-O load command (changing a single byte) around `VERSION_MIN_MAC_OSX` to point to 10.12.0 rather than 10.13.0 also fixes things.

Comment: Does passing `-mmacosx-version-min=10.12` to the compiler help?

Comment: Passing the flag `-mmacosx-version-min=10.12` didn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: If you do `otool -lV <path>` on the hacked and unhacked executable, what value were you changing that had an effect, `version` or `sdk`?

Comment: It's `sdk` that needs to be 10.12.0 in order for things to work — rather than 10.13.0. Essentially changing `0D` to `0C` does the trick.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I initially figured, but your mention of `VERSION_MIN_MAC_OSX` made me think that, maybe, the deployment target mattered. If it's the SDK version, then I'm not sure there's much you can do. It's common (and documented, in many cases) that the system frameworks change their behavior based on the linked SDK version of the executable. That's to maintain backward compatibility for existing apps while allowing the frameworks to move forward for newly-linked apps. It's expected that, if you rebuild your app against a new SDK, you account for the changed behavior.

Comment: Yeah — I agree that it's common and usually documented, and this is what I expect is the case here too — the only issue is that I can not find any explicit documentation around this change anywhere.

I really wish Apple would re-up their documentation game.

It looks like I'll move towards OpenGL-provided FBO — well-knowing that Metal is what I should already be working against.

Thanks Ken :)